# CVMetalTextureGetTexture ownerhsip?

Tags: objective-c, swift, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation, core-video

I'm trying to figure out how the ownership works with the function `CVMetalTextureGetTexture`:

```
CVMetalTextureRef textureRef;
// ... textureRef is created
id<MTLTexture> texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(_textureRef);
CVBufferRelease(textureRef); // Releasing the existing texture
// Is texture still valid here?
```

Is `texture` still valid after releasing `textureRef`? If not, can I somehow transfer ownership from `textureRef` to `texture` (ARC), so I don't have to call `CVBufferRelease` later when `texture` is released?

The same question for swift:

```
var texture: MTLTexture
do {
  var textureRef: CVMetalTexture
  // ... textureRef is created
  texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(textureRef)!
  // end of scope, textureRef is released
}
// Is texture still valid here?
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at the file `MetalCameraSession.swift` of this [GitHub Reporsitory](https://github.com/navoshta/MetalRenderCamera).

Comment: @mschmidt Thanks for the comment! I can't be sure, though, if the guy at this repository did everything correctly, or has memory issues with his code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent question since this kind of breaks the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029), but it seems like this method indeed retains the underlying object. I guess this rule doesn't apply for Core Foundation -> ARC methods...

You can see in [this Apple Demo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/displaying_an_ar_experience_with_metal) that they do release the ref after converting it to an `id<MTLTexture>`. They do it in the more implicit Swifty version so it's easily missed.

Answer (score 1):

We have also made another experiment before I see your question:

`in a loop, CVMetalTextureRef created from CVPixelBuffer comes from Camera.`

```
static void *texturePtr;  

/** AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, as a loop */
{
CVMetalTextureRef textureRef;
// ... textureRef is created
id<MTLTexture> texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(_textureRef);
CVBufferRelease(textureRef); // Releasing the existing texture

texturePtr= (__bridge_retained void*)texture;

// no releasing the texturePtr
// (__bridge_transfer id<MTLTexture>)texturePtr;
}
```

I found that I did not `release` the `texturePtr`, but still `no memory leak` occurs. What's more, `texturePtr` is `valid` in sometime and before we replace it with the new var.
So I think maybe this is linked to your question.
My reply is more like an argument other than an answer.